# How to subtract months from YYYYMM string date in python?

Tags: python, date-formatting

I have strings that are dates(`YYYYMM` such as: `201909`.

In Python, how can I simply subtract one month?

```
from datetime import datetime

Month = '201905'
Month = datetime.strptime(Month, '%Y%m').date()
Month1 = str(Month -1)
Month2 = str(Month -2)
Month3 = str(Month -3)
Month6 = str(Month -6)
Month12 = str(Month - 100)
```

This doesn't work, but I would like to be able to set the 'Month' variable to a string like '201905' and calculate various YYYYMM strings from there.

Comment: Are you working with pandas?

Comment: In short: `dateutil.relativedelta`.  Full code below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will give desired month as `int`:

```
Month = '201905'
Month = datetime.strptime(Month, '%Y%m').date()
month = Month.month # this is an int, you can easily subtract it
print (Month.month)
```

Comment: this is the wrong answer.. he is asking how to subtract a month from it

Comment: @YatishKadam when you've month number, then you can easily subtract it

Comment: yea but when you are give an half answer it should be mentioned as such..

Answer (score 3):

This solution is both **simple** and **robust**.  It utilises time-tested built-in packages and will bring you into the previous year, rather than just subtracting (n) from the month number.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# User's original values.
string = '201905'
dte = dt.strptime(string, '%Y%m').date()
# Calculate one months previous.
result = dte + relativedelta(months=-1)

# Display path and results
print('Original string value: {}'.format(string))
print('Original datetime value: {}'.format(dte))
print('Result (original minus two months): {}'.format(result))
```

The output:

```
Original string value: 201905
Original datetime value: 2019-05-01
Result (original minus one month): 2019-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

i am leveraging the fact that its a string.
Extract the last two MM from the string using

> Month[-2:] -> this will give you 01 - 12 range.

the only condition you would need to check for is when it is 0. ( i am assuming you will always get a valid YYYYMM.

```
Month = '201912' 
month = 12 if (int(Month[-2:]) -1 ) % 12 == 0 else (int(Month[-2:]) -1 ) % 12
year = int(Month[:-2]) - 1 if month == 12 else int(Month[:-2])

print (str(year)+str(month))
```

Comment: What about the year?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for any arbitrary decrement up to 12 months

```
old_date_string = '201901'
decrement = 1
year = int(old_date_string[:-2])
month = int(old_date_string[-2:])
month = month - decrement
if month<1: 
  month = month + 12
  year = year - 1
new_date_string = str(year) + '{:02d}'.format(month)
print(new_date_string)
```